# Rescaling issue with pdfjs library

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

**Objective**

I'm trying to render each pages of a pdf document in a certain space box. these boxes are 375px height and 265px width.

**The issue**

I currently managed to scale my page correctly on the x-axis but the page still got the same height as it has before the rescaling operation.

**Configuration**

- Chrome
- Window 10
- PDF.js version: 2.6.347

**Steps to reproduce the problem**

1. Create a canvas sized as i said before. (w: 265px, h: 375px)
2. Get a rescaled viewport by doing this (with page a pdf page obtained thank to the "getPage() method")

```
var desiredWidth = canvas.width;
var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1, });
var scale = desiredWidth / viewport.width;
var scaledViewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale});
```

3. Render the page in the canvas with the canvas context and rescaled viewport by doing this

```
let renderContext = {
    canvasContext: context,
    viewport: scaledViewport
};

await page.render(renderContext);
```

**What i expected**

get a canvas containing the entire page correctly rescaled.

**What i obtain**

A canvas containing the entire width of the page but only the first 375px of the page height. That means that the page has been correctly rescaled on x-axis but nothing changed on the y-axis..

**Exemple**

So a document like this

[Original](https://ibb.co/3dBnMFR)

Look like this in my canvas

[In canvas](https://ibb.co/JCWBdHm)

I don't know what i'm missing there ... i reproduce exactly what is in the pdfjs library documentation to render a pdf page in a defined spacebox

Comment: whether your canvas is not scaling or its content ?

Comment: No it's content, my canvas is correctly scaled

Comment: can you reproduce your problem ? or show some image. i'm not sure that your explanation of problem is clear for everyone.

Comment: I'm sorry i literally forget to come back on my post, i solved the issue.It was because i was setting my canvas size by setting the styles parameters "width" and "height" in pixels instead of setting directly the attributes "width" and "height".

Comment: so your canvas wasn't correctly scaled :)

Comment: Yes in fact you are right. But visually talking, my canvas was correctly scaled but its content wasn't ans that is why i didn't know it was because of the canvas